# Extract public key from PKey in pyOpenSSL

Tags: python, security, pyopenssl

I'm using pyOpenSSL, and when generating a request. I've basically been doing

```
import OpenSSL
from OpenSSL import crypto
key = crypto.PKey()
key.generate(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 1024)
req = crypto.X509Req()
req.get_subject().CN = "Anonymous"
req.set_pubkey(key)
req.sign(key, "sha1")
```

However, I feel I'm doing something wrong because I believe I just set the public key of the request to the private key instead of the public key.

I'm wondering if I did this wrong, and if so, how do I extract the public key from the private key pair in pyOpenSSL. It is unclear to me how to do this from the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

OpenSSL.crypto.PKey().generate() creates a public/pair. So you should be okay.

See http://pythonhosted.org/pyOpenSSL/openssl-pkey.html